# Resize Image in PHP Using Croppie

Tags: php, crop, image-resizing

I am trying to resize an image which is taken from a cropping tool used on my form. The code below is being used with the library [Croppie](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/).

```
if($_POST['imagebase64'] != '') {
    $data = $_POST['imagebase64'];

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    file_put_contents(APPPATH.'../assets/image64.png', $data);
}
```

I would like to know how to resize the image before pushing it to the server. Preferably, I would like to use stock php, something like `imagecopyresampled` but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's `gd` and `imagemagick` as the usual suspects, but this is not a question for Stackoverflow yet; instead of asking for how to start, just find *a* start, see if that works for you, and if you get stuck on it that's the time to ask Stackoverflow for help. Image uploads with resizing etc. is something that plenty of people have written tutorials for, find those first?

Comment: You can't use PHP to resize an image before it's pushed to the server; PHP runs _on_ the server, and can only access the image after it's been uploaded.

Comment: as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans said, you have **PHP GD** http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php, and [**imagemagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)